# Google sheet - lookup multiple values in a range and return only with rows that DON'T match

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

The lookup values are in column C and D in the first table (pic 1). I am looking for a formula (query, arrayformula, etc) which would:

1. return ALL the rows from the second table (pic 2) IF non of the values match in column F:O 
   AND
2. filter only the results where column E (pic 2) matches with cell D2 (pic 1).

I hope it makes sense.

Here is a link to the spreadsheet:
[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ui5RQIYVPMc1ApVJI5_vMk90dLvqO52Mp4SvzeNcGJw/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

[image]

Comment: @player0 link added, thanks!

Comment: could you also pls add the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
={'Classroom Management'!D1:E1; 
 FILTER('Classroom Management'!D10:E, 'Classroom Management'!E10:E=D2, 
 NOT(REGEXMATCH('Classroom Management'!Z10:Z, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C2:C11))))}
```

[image: 0]